# Without clicking the button its click event executing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form which contains a input text and a button.
**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
   <input type="text" />
   <button onclick='YouClick();'>Click</button>
 </form>
```

JS function

```
 function YouClick() {
   alert("You just clicked");
 }
```

When user click the button , the javascript function `YouClick` executes. But if i pressed enter key on input text fields than also `YouClick` function executes. How can i stop this behaviour ? So that only by clicking the button the `YouClick` function executes.

Comment: Your button is inside the form. So when you are pressing the enter button its being pressed. Put it outside the form and see. Its not a solution. Solutions are given below. I am just telling you the reason

Comment: @NejiHyuga: why would you need a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are submitting the form, then the button which by default is `type='submit'` is triggered,  you can set the type attribute of the button as `button`:

```
<button type='button' onclick='YouClick();'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `return false ===  event.preventDefault + event.stopPropagation();`